# Noise Reduction in an Audio file using Python

Tags: python, wav

We can perform noise reduction using Open-source Software like Audacity, which is commonly used for the purpose. Please click the below link for reference.

[denoising with audacity image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Plj3V.png)

Is there a python library that can perform a similar function?

Comment: yeah there is lots of libraries which can do this

Comment: Thanks you for your answer @Arpit Solanki.I tried the scipy.filtfilt function but it smoothed the signal but didn't remove the noise.Do you know what librarie i could use?

Comment: @samourayonly Updated my answer including a general guideline.

Comment: Thanks you so much @RussellB. I just applied a high-pass filter with audacity and it did the same work that the noise reduction. Now i know that i must use a high-pass filter.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to reduce noise the audacity way, to my understanding, you should program your algorithm using scipy filters provided by [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/signal.html) library.

Besides that `pyaudio` is one dedicated library for audio analysis and [here](https://healthyalgorithms.com/2013/08/22/dsp-in-python-active-noise-reduction-with-pyaudio/) is a kickstart tutorial.

If you are not restricted only to `Python`, you can check out on [Essentia](http://essentia.upf.edu/documentation/). This is by far an exhaustive library for music and audio analysis.

Nutshell: While python libraries provide functionalities, it is you who should code your noise reduction algorithm (tailored to your needs). May be you can follow the audacity's approach.

You can refer this question for better, technical/implementation, clarity: Noise [reduction on wave file](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/24918/noise-reduction-on-wave-file)

Good luck! Try to be precise and post questions focusing on implementation pertaining to programming languages rather than generic things.

**As a general guideline:**
Understand the behavior of your noise and then you can choose your noise removal strategy accordingly.May be you need a simple low pass filter or high-pass filter.