# How to increase accuracy in python speechrecognition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, pydub

I want to convert some audio files to text in offline mode using SpeechRecognition module. I am able to convert it but it's 0% accurate. Can anyone suggest how to make it more accurate?
Here's the code I am using:

```
def convert_wav_to_text(path):
    """
    Splitting the large audio file into chunks
    and apply speech recognition on each of these chunks
    """
    # open the audio file using pydub
    sound = AudioSegment.from_wav(path)
    # split audio sound where silence is 700 miliseconds or more and get chunks
    chunks = split_on_silence(sound,
        # experiment with this value for your target audio file
        min_silence_len = 500,
        # adjust this per requirement
        silence_thresh = sound.dBFS-14,
        # keep the silence for 1 second, adjustable as well
        keep_silence=500,
    )
    folder_name = "audio-chunks"
    # create a directory to store the audio chunks
    if not os.path.isdir(folder_name):
        os.mkdir(folder_name)
    whole_text = ""
    # process each chunk
    for i, audio_chunk in enumerate(chunks, start=1):
        # export audio chunk and save it in
        # the `folder_name` directory.
        chunk_filename = os.path.join(folder_name, f"chunk{i}.wav")
        audio_chunk.export(chunk_filename, format="wav")
        # recognize the chunk
        with sr.AudioFile(chunk_filename) as source:
            audio_listened = r.record(source)
            # try converting it to text
            try:
                text = r.recognize_sphinx(audio_listened)
            except sr.UnknownValueError as e:
                print("Error:", str(e))
            else:
                text = f"{text.capitalize()}. "
                whole_text += text
    # return the text for all chunks detected
    num = path.split('.')[0]
    file = open(num+'.txt', 'w')
    file.write(whole_text)
    file.close()

convert_wav_to_text("1.wav")
```

I am attaching the audio file also: [1.wav](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j6gm1DGMoJc_mShKs8KvyzhEWzodpW3d/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: 0% accurate? Have you tested it on some other file to see if it works?

Comment: Reduce noise in the audio. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45118109/noise-reduction-in-an-audio-file-using-python) , to know in detail.

Comment: Yes, it's not giving any relevant word to the audio file.